# Detect wrong data from ReadFile

Tags: c, windows, readfile

I have a function that is supposed to read a .dat file containing an array of structs defined as:

```
struct data{
  char name[30];
  double age;
}

struct data buffer[80];
```

No other data is allowed in the file.

I want to protect the user from reading files that don't contain the above struct. If I try to read some random .docx file or something then there's a very high likelihood of an error.

How can I make sure that the user can't read a file that he or she isn't supposed to? Is there perhaps a way to find out if the data in the file is a struct or something else?

I'm using the ReadFile function and saving the data into the buffer for this.

It isn't enough to simply make sure that it's a .dat file since such a file could contain anything.

Comment: Put a signature in your file. Or just trust the user.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a special signature (whatever you choose) at the beginning of the file, as many file formats do. For instance, all .ZIP files contain

```
50 4B 05 06 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

(which is 'PK', followed by '0x05', '0x06', and 18 NULL bytes).

You simply first read the number of bytes equal to the size of your file signature from the file and compare it to your signature. If they match, you start reading at the first byte after the length of the signature to the end of the file.

If your file always contains 80 data structures, you could add an extra validation by reading the file size, subtracting the number of bytes used for the signature, and dividing the remainder by the size of 80 data structures. If both the signature and the byte sizes match, it's probably your file.

After your edit, which indicates you're unable to modify the structure of the data file, the second option is really the only viable one. Simply remove the portion related to skipping over the signature size bytes; read the size of the file in bytes and divide it by `sizeof(data)`, and it should equal 80. It's not a perfect solution, but without being able to modify the layout to add something more specific it's probably the best you can do.

Comment: The problem is that it's supposed to be able to read a file given in the specification for this project that I'm doing. So that won't work.

Comment: Alright I did. There's something to your last point though. I could check if the file size is a multiple of sizeof(data). It's not full proof though.

Comment: You should have posted that requirement in your question before I spent my time answering it without knowing that fact. Then my second suggestion is the only option; just leave out the part that subtracts the size of the signature, and use the file size divided by the structure size - it should divide evenly with no remainder. It certainly isn't fool-proof, but you've indicated you can't do anything to make it so (now).

Answer (score 0):

Read your data, then check if

1. `name` is a zero-terminated string of minimally 1 and maximally 29 characters. *At least* it should not contain characters lower than space and the character codes `0x7F` and `0xFF`. Perhaps you can test more -- if you entered these names as UTF-8, then all codes higher than or equal to `0x80` should match the UTF-8 specification.
2. `age` should be a valid `double` number, and be in a certain range. An age of `-0.005`, for instance, is obviously invalid; and so is `4.7E14`.
3. Set unused bytes after the terminating zero in the `name` array to a 'known' value or sequence. On reading, test if you get the expected bytes back.

This should hold true for all of the items in your little database.

If you can expand the existing struct, you could devise a 'magic' checksum and append it. Then if the re-calculation of this checksum does not match the stored one, something is wrong. A checksum can be as simple as adding all bytes together and storing only the lowest byte, or XORing them together, or using Adler-32 or CRC32, depending on how safe you want it.

(Before creating a checksum, better make sure you set the unused bytes of your `name` array to a known, fixed value.)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged with Windows, I would stick the signature in an [alternate file stream](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/105763/en-us). That way you don't modify the required file format, but still have the flexibility of storing a strong signature that moves along with the file.

Although this does lock you into using NTFS filesystems.